# Using gridle or SASS libraries in Webpack

Tags: sass, webpack

How do I use [gridle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridle) in Webpack? I'm attempting to import it to use within my project but I'm getting an error.

I attempted the following:

1. Installed via NPM: `npm i gridle --save`
2. Imported gridle into `entry.js`
3. Created file `grid.scss` and attempted to use a gridle mixin.
4. Imported `grid.scss` below gridle in `entry.js`

**entry.js**

```
import "fabric"
import "gridle"
import "../scss/fonts.scss"
import "../scss/grid.scss"
```

**grid.scss**

```
@include gridle_setup((
  context : 12,
  gutter-width : 20px,
  direction : rtl,
));
```

The error I am getting is:

```
@include gridle_setup((
        ^
      No mixin named gridle-setup
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  `@import "~gridle/sass/grid";`  in your scss file. it work